# How to bind image from json to xaml in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, json.net

I am new to windows phone development. I'm working on an app that fetches json from webservice and parse it using json.net to display data in windows phone. here's the sample json.

```
[
{
    "id": "001",
    "title": "title1",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "3",
    "image": "defaultimg.jpg"
},

{
    "id": "021",
    "title": "title2",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "1",
    "image": "defaultimg2.jpg"
},

{
    "id": "011",
    "title": "title3",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "3",
    "image": "defaultimg22.jpg"
},
]
```

is it possible to bind the image with that kind of format? or it should be in url format?

Comment: You must bind image source with an absolute or relative url of an existing image or an image object. You can use a converter to convert those json string to an url when binding but it is obviously not a smart way to do.

Comment: Thanks @DavidTo can you provide some links to convert json string to an url?

Comment: It will be easier if you use the json.net library itself to parse string into json object. About Converter, you can follow example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or google about how to write IValueConverter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing then image path, pass a base64 encoded image string and then use that in the view.